# Routing IPv6 through a Cisco RV042 in gateway mode

Tags: cisco, routing, ipv6

I am having some difficulty routing IPv6 through a Cisco RV042 in gateway mode. I am attempting to simulate a small IPv6 WAN between two offices using a /48 prefix. Nothing I do in the advanced routing setup enables me to get packets through the router. Has anyone any experience in successfully setting up IPv6 routing on this device?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry; but SOHO routers from Linksys (now cisco) have no IPv6 support.

Comment: Not completely true. The latest RV042 hardware and software support IPv6. Also see the review on http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-reviews/31502-cisco-rv042-v3-dual-wan-vpn-router-reviewed